# Binary Tree In Dafny

Tags: binary-tree, dafny

problem from the office -  frontier of the tree is the sequence of tip-values in left-to-right order.
i need to develop iterative code that prints the frontier of a given tree
using the OUTPUT method of the following IO class

```
class IO<T> {
    var alpha: seq<T>, omega: seq<T>;

    method Input() returns (x: T)
        requires !EOF() //alpha != []
        modifies this
        ensures omega == old(omega)
        ensures old(alpha) == [x] + alpha
    {
        x, alpha := alpha[0], alpha[1..];
    }

    method Output(x: T)
        modifies this
        ensures alpha == old(alpha)
        ensures omega == old(omega) + [x]
    {
        omega := omega + [x];
    }

    method Rewrite()
        modifies this
        ensures omega == []
        ensures alpha == old(alpha)
    {
        omega := [];
    }

    predicate method EOF() reads this { alpha == [] }

}

method Main()
{
    var tree: BT<int>;
    tree := Tip(1);
    var io: IO<int>;
    io := new IO<int>;
    FrontierIter(tree, io);
    print io.omega;

    io.Rewrite();
    tree := Node(tree, Tip(2));
    FrontierIter(tree, io);
    print io.omega;
}

function Frontier(tree: BT<T>): seq<T>
{
    match tree {
        case Tip(n) => [n]
        case Node(left, right) => Frontier(left) + Frontier(right)
    }
}

method FrontierIter(tree: BT<T>, io: IO<T>)
    requires io != null
    modifies io
    ensures io.omega == old(io.omega) + Frontier(tree)
{
    var stack: seq<BT<T>>;
    stack := [tree];
```

Comment: I can't quite understand the question. Can you perhaps show us any attempt you have made at such an iterative procedure?